# Scanf is causing infinite loop

Tags: c

I have a C program for Guess the number game but when I run this code it goes into infinite loop, I think it's because of scanf() in the 11th line! How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
    int number, guess, nguesses = 1;
    char name;
    srand(time(0));
    number = rand()%100 + 1; // Generates a random number between 1 and 100
    // Keeps running the loop until the number is guessed
    printf("------| Welcome to Guess the number game |-------\n");
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%c", name); ---> Causing infinite loop

    do
    {
        printf("\nGuess the number between 1 to 100\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if(guess>number)
        printf("Lower number please!\n");
        else if(guess<number)
        {
            printf("Higher nummber please!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Congratulations you have correctly guessed the number!\nAttempts taken: %d\n", nguesses); 
        }
        nguesses++;
    } 
    while (guess!=number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%c", name);` - you're going to run into many problems, when you define name as `char name;`

Comment: Hint: always check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you don't want `name` to be a single character. If you want it to be, say, up to 20 characters long (plus the terminating null character), you want `char n[21];` and `scanf("%20s",n);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]When you declare `name`, you signed it for `char` but names has no only one character. So it must be an `array`, and while you scanf, you use `%s` instead of `%c`. (`%c` for char, `%s` for char array{you can think like string}). I tried what ı wrote in here and enjoyed your game.

```
char name[10]; //or any number
scanf("%s", name);
```

Comment: Thnx for the help! 